# How to type this optimization problem in latex without equation number

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath, ieeetran

I am writing a paper in IEEE Transactions on signal processing. I need to write the attached optimization problem in one column of the paper without the equation number.

[image]

The code I have tried is

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{\null}{\text{find}}
& & X \\
& \text{subject to}
& & \A(X)=y \\
&&& X \succeq 0\\
&&& \rk(X=1)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{\null}{\text{minimize}}
& & \rk(X) \\
& \text{subject to}
& & \A(X)=y \\
&&& X \succeq 0\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

But the result it has produced is

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should take a look at the `optidef` package.

Comment: @Bernard ; That package doesn't answer how to write two optimization problems side by side. Can you write the code for me?

Comment: I thought you might try  writing two optimisation environments within a single `\[ … \]`.

Comment: @Bernard ; How can I write find instead of minimize? please see the attached image.

Answer (score 1):

Finally it doesn't seem to be possible to make it work with `optidef`. So I propose a solution with two `alignedat` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, optidef}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{rank}

\begin{document}

  \[ \begin{alignedat}{2}
     & \text{Find} & & X \\
     & \text{subject to} & \quad & \mathcal{A}(X) \ge 0 \\
     & & & X \succeq 0 \\
     & & & \rk(X) = 1
  \end{alignedat}\quad \iff \quad
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
   & \text{Minimise} && \rk(X) \\
  & \text{subject to} & \quad &\mathcal{A}(X ) = b \\
     & & & X \succeq 0
  \end{alignedat} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: To make this optimisation problem fit within a single column, I propose this code with the `alignat*` environment and the `\ArrowBetweenLines` command from `mathtools`:

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
     & \text{Find} & & X \\
     & \text{subject to} & \quad & \mathcal{A}(X) ≥ 0 \\
     & & & X \succeq 0 \\
     & & & \rk(X) = 1 \\
  \ArrowBetweenLines 
   & \text{Minimise} && \rk(X) \\
  & \text{subject to} & \quad &\mathcal{A}(X ) = b \\
     & & & X \succeq 0
  \end{alignat*}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks man! But the problem is that the above code produces a result that spans both the columns of my paper. How can I shift it to the left side of the page?

Comment: You may try with a `gather*` environment an put the `alignedat` environments in different lines.

Comment: I tried gather* environment but it doesn't work

Comment: @shashankranjan: what do you mean exactly? Is the result still wider than a column?

Comment: @shashankranjan: I've added another solution, that should fit a single column.

Comment: @Bernard,  If for documentclass you use `ieeetran` than your first solution fit in one column nicely. OP should extend her/his code fragment to MWE that we will know her/his document layout.