# Big optimization expression spanning both the columns of IEEE paper

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath, ieeetran

I have tried the following code:

```
\[ \begin{alignedat}{2}
& \text{Find} & & X \\
& \text{subject to} & \quad & \mathcal{A}(X) = y \\
& & & X \succeq 0 \\
& & & \rk(X) = 1
\end{alignedat}\quad \iff \quad
\begin{alignedat}{2}
& \text{Minimise} && \rk(X) \\
& \text{subject to} & \quad &\mathcal{A}(X ) = y \\
& & & X \succeq 0
\end{alignedat} \]
```

But the result it has produced is:

[image]

As you can see the optimization expression is spanning both the column of the paper.
My question is how can I shift this optimization expression to the left side of the paper?

Comment: How does this question differ from this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/649670 ?  (It looks like you have two accounts; ask the mods for help combining them.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I guess this question takes [Bernard's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/649678/5001) to the earlier question as its starting point.

Comment: @Mico -- That's not hard to figure out.  But ideally, a reference should have been given.  There's also the problem of multiple user accounts.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you abbreviate both instances of `subject to` to `s.t.` and the lone instance of `Minimise` to `Min.`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{Rank}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\[ 
\begin{alignedat}{2}
& \text{Find} & \quad & X \\
& \text{s.t.} & & \mathcal{A}(X) = y \\
& & & X \succeq 0 \\
& & & \rk(X) = 1
\end{alignedat}
\quad \iff \quad
\begin{alignedat}{2}
& \text{Min.} & \quad & \rk(X) \\
& \text{s.t.} & &\mathcal{A}(X ) = y \\
& & & X \succeq 0
\end{alignedat} 
\]
\lipsum[2] % filler rtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is using a math font that

1. is visually incompatible with the text font
2. has an average character width quite larger than the text font

Now, IEEEtran uses Times as the main text font and two column format for a very simple reason: to squeeze much more text in each page.

Using Computer Modern Math for the mathematical parts of your paper makes for very bad typesetting and has readability issues. So the first step to take when you have to use IEEEtran is to switch to Times also for math formulas.

The older hack was declaring `\usepackage{mathptmx}`, but you can now use NewTX that's actively maintained and has been present in TeX distributions for several years.

With this your display will fit nicely. I replaced the too long `\iff` with `\Leftrightarrow` and fixed `\mathcal` (which in NewTX is not as nice). I also added a version with the mid arrow aligned with the top lines of the optimization problems.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}% or just \usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[cal=cm]{mathalpha}% for standard \mathcal

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{rank}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]
\[
\begin{alignedat}{2}
& \text{Find} & & X \\
& \text{subject to} & \quad & \mathcal{A}(X) = y \\
& & & X \succeq 0 \\
& & & \rk(X) = 1
\end{alignedat}
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
\begin{alignedat}{2}
& \text{Minimise} && \rk(X) \\
& \text{subject to} & \quad &\mathcal{A}(X ) = y \\
& & & X \succeq 0
\end{alignedat}
\]
\lipsum[1-4]
\[
\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
& \text{Find} & & X \\
& \text{subject to} & \quad & \mathcal{A}(X) = y \\
& & & X \succeq 0 \\
& & & \rk(X) = 1
\end{alignedat}
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
& \text{Minimise} && \rk(X) \\
& \text{subject to} & \quad &\mathcal{A}(X ) = y \\
& & & X \succeq 0
\end{alignedat}
\]
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]